# How to place Admod view fixed at bottom for all Activities

Tags: android

When start new Activity, admod reload. I want admod fixed all activities.
Am using below code

```
mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

and layout:

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_home_footer"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            >
        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Help me!

Comment: So what is the problem here ? Add AdView to each activity where you want to show Ads

Comment: i want admod not reload when new activity starting, admod fixed in one locaion and not settup again

Comment: It is not possible. If you open new activity AdView will render again. But if you have multiple views where you traverse between them. then use fragment in activity. place AdView in activity constant and replace fragment to traverse between views

Answer (score 0):

You can use one activity with `AdView` in one fragment and content in another fragment. The content can be in fragments. So banners would not be reloaded on each `onCreate` of activities.

Answer (score 0):

As an example I use this in my app. It is my main activity and opens other fragments inside it.

Mainactivity layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adViewMain"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_bannerbottommain"></com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Mainactivity code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ..........

    //Loading AdMob
    mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adViewMain);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)        // All emulators
                .addTestDevice("YOUR DEVICE IN HERE")  // Your device ID
                .build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

    ..........

}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    // Resume the AdView.
    mAdView.resume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    // Pause the AdView.
    mAdView.pause();

    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    // Destroy the AdView.
    mAdView.destroy();

    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Don't forget the onResume(), onPause() and onDestroy() part. Or it will, in my case, lead to a battery drainage bug.